# How to format print statement with ANSI Escape Codes using variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, ansi-escape, rich

I know I can do `print(f"\033[32m{newList[0]}\033[0m", f"\033[32m{newList[1]}\033[0m")` to print a list value in color,

But how would I make the 32m into a variable and make it work?

How would I make the 32m changeable with a variable?

Ex.

```
dic = {
        "greetings": ["hello", "bonjour"],
        "goodbyes": ["adios", "4"]
    }
newList = ["hola", "barev"]
dic.update({"greetings": newList})
color = 32
hola = dic["greetings"][0]
print(f"\033[", color, "m{newList[0]}\033[0m", f"\033[", color, "m{newList[1]}\033[0m")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own code works fine if you make all the strings in the `print` function [*f-strings*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) by appending an `f` before the opening quote:

```py
print(f"\033[", color, f"m{newList[0]}\033[0m", f"\033[", color, f"m{newList[1]}\033[0m")
```

Output:

```
hola barev
```

Or just make it one long f-string:

```py
print(f"\033[{color}m{newList[0]}\033[0m\033[{color}m {newList[1]}\033[0m")
```

Output:

```
hola barev
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but what about whenever I use a dictionary instead of a list?

EX. 

`newdict = {
        "greetings": ["hello", "bonjour"],
        "goodbyes": ["adios", "4"]
    }
newList = ["hola", "barev"]
newdict.update({"greetings": newList})
color = [33, 32]
hola = newdict["greetings"][0]
def Test():
    for i in range(3):
        print("|", f"\033[{color[0]}m{newdict["greetings"][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[1]}m{newList[1]}\033[0m")

Test()`

Comment: No problemo. The double quote in `newdict["greetings"][0]` terminates the string prematurely. So either change the double quotes in the square brackets to single quotes, or make the whole string a _triple quoted string_. So, respectively: `print("|", f"\033[{color[0]}m{newdict['greetings'][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[1]}m {newList[1]}\033[0m")` and `print("|", f"""\033[{color[0]}m{newdict["greetings"][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[1]}m {newList[1]}\033[0m""")`. Be sure to read [2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: I have another question but it doesn't fit in the comments. I made a new question, can you please respond there? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284106/how-to-format-print-statement-using-ansi-codes-using-function