# How to format print statement using ANSI Codes using function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, ansi-escape, rich

I know I can do `print(f"\033[32m{newDict[0][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[32m{newDict[1][1]}\033[0m")` to print a dictionary value in color,

But I'm putting that into a for loop inside a function and its output is weird and not the output for what I want.

INPUT:

```
board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}


def boardprint(color):
    global board

    for x in range(6):
        print(" |", f"\033[{color[0]}m{board[x + 1][0]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[1]}m{board[x + 1][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[2]}m{board[x + 1][2]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[3]}m{board[x + 1][3]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[4]}m{board[x + 1][4]}\033[0m", "|")
```

OUTPUT:

```
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
 | [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m [39m_[0m |
```

How do I fix this so that it just prints `_` for each value/tile?

FULL CODE:

```
from rich import print
import random

testList = ["PRICE"]
word = random.choice(testList)


board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}


def boardprint(color):
    global board

    for x in range(6):
        print(" |", f"\033[{color[0]}m{board[x + 1][0]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[1]}m{board[x + 1][1]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[2]}m{board[x + 1][2]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[3]}m{board[x + 1][3]}\033[0m", f"\033[{color[4]}m{board[x + 1][4]}\033[0m", "|")




guess = ""
def ask():
    global guess
    print("hello! welcome to [bold green]WORDLE[/bold green]")
    print("\tTry to guess a 5-letter word in 6 guesses or less.\n\t\tIf a letter is [green]green[/green], then it is in the right place,\n\t\tIf a letter is [yellow]yellow[/yellow], then it is in the wrong place, \n\t\tif a letter is [black]grey[/black], then it is the wrong letter.")
    print()
    guess = input("FIRST GUESS  > ").upper()
    guess = list(guess)

    return guess


colorList = [39, 39, 39, 39, 39]
def checkRight(guess, word, row):
    global board, colorList

    GuessCheckDouble = {i:guess.count(i) for i in guess}
    WordCheckDouble = {i:word.count(i) for i in word}
    result = {key: GuessCheckDouble[key] - WordCheckDouble.get(key, 0) for key in GuessCheckDouble.keys()}
    updateRow = []

    for x in range(len(word)):
        if guess[x].upper() == word[x]: # green
            print("green")
            
            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(str(letter))
            colorList[x] = 39

        elif guess[x].upper() in word and result[guess[x]] == 0: # yellow
            print("Yellow")
            
            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(letter)
            
        else: # grey
            print("grey")

            letter = guess[x]
            updateRow.append(letter)

    board.update({row : [updateRow[0], updateRow[1], updateRow[2], updateRow[3], updateRow[4]]})
    boardprint(colorList)



    return board, colorList

word = word.upper()
word = list(word)

boardprint(colorList)
ask()
print(guess)

checkRight(guess, word, 1)
print(word)
print(board)
boardprint(colorList)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific purposes, you don't need `rich`, and its `print` function is actually causing your problems because by itself, it seems to mangle the ANSI sequences.

You can do this with Python built-ins only:

```
board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}

def boardprint(colors):
    global board

    final = []
    for x in range(len(board)):
        spots = [f"\033[{col}m{board[x+1][idx]}\33[0m" for idx,col in enumerate(colors)]
        l = ' '.join(spots)
        final.append(f"| {l} |")
    print('\n'.join(final))

colors = [31, 31, 31, 31, 31]
boardprint(colors)
```

And if your terminal/console recognizes these codes, you'll get something like this (changed it to `red` code since your `39` code is just a color-reset.

[image: board image with red]

---

If you want to use the `rich` module, it's preferable to just use their [color codes](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix/colors.html#appendix-colors).

```
import rich

board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}

def rich_boardprint(colors):
    global board

    final = []
    for x in range(len(board)):
        spots = [f"[{col}]{board[x+1][idx]}[/]" for idx,col in enumerate(colors)]
        l = ' '.join(spots)
        final.append(f"| {l} |")
    rich.print('\n'.join(final))

rich_colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "magenta", "green"]
rich_boardprint(rich_colors)
```

And this will look like this:

[image]

---

If you want to continue using the ANSI codes as-is, but with `rich.print`, you can use some additional features of the `rich` library to translate your ANSI text to something it understands, using [`rich.text.Text.from_ansi`](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/text.html#rich.text.Text.from_ansi), like this:

```
import rich
from rich.text import Text

board = {
    6 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    5 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    4 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    3 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    2 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"],
    1 : ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
}

def ansi_rich_boardprint(colors):
    global board

    final = []
    for x in range(len(board)):
        spots = [f"\033[{col}m{board[x+1][idx]}\33[0m" for idx,col in enumerate(colors)]
        l = ' '.join(spots)
        final.append(f"| {l} |")
    ansi_rich = Text.from_ansi('\n'.join(final))
    rich.print(ansi_rich)

colors = [31, 31, 31, 31, 31]
ansi_rich_boardprint(colors)
```

And you'll get an image like the first example that only uses built-in `print`:

[image]